# Does probability change with time?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

My question is will probability distribution change with time if some function is affected somehow by time. And in what way it will change.
e.g. consider i know a person who checks his messages at least after half an hour but there is also chance that he will check them at any moment in between half hour interval. If i send a message at random time without knowing when last time he checked it, how will probability of seeing message change at any instant or for seconds?

Comment: at $t=0$, the probability is zero and at $t=30$ minutes, the probability is one. How the probability as a function of time looks in that interval depends on the chance that your friend checks it at any moment, which is poorly defined. If he checked it at exact $30$ minute intervals throughout the day, then the function would be linear. If he didn't necessarily check exactly every half hour but checked it *on average* every half hour, then the function would be a [poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution).

Comment: In probability reality is modeled. There are models that include time somehow. For instance a (non homogeneous) Poisson process.

Comment: Yes i understand it will increase to t=30 min to 1 but how can we surely say that at t 0 it will be 0 and also i want to know if there is equal chance of looking in between interval how will probabolity function change.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer for your specific constraint is:  No

In your example, you make a single claim regarding time:  "person who checks his messages at least after half an hour".    So in this case, the probability that the message will be checked in the next 30 minutes is 1.

You give no basis for calculating any probability of the time dependent action variable "...if they have time...", so you have nothing to use.  The only time aspect you can calculate for your scenario is the probability of when within the 30 minute repeat cycle the message is received, which are all equally likely.

Certainly there are probability distributions that have time as a variable, but this occurs only when the time variable is well defined, just like any other domain quantity, something which your example fails to do.   You are basically asking "I pick a bead from a totally unknown quantity of beads, how does the probability of picking a white bead change when the total number of beads changes?"

Comment: Ok as i comented if, there is no chance of if he have time but there is equal chance that he will check at any instant then what.

Comment: But he will check at atleast at every half hour

Comment: And also this thing- if he checks between interval it will not change to next interval he will be in same interval of 30 min and again check after remaining time from 30 min

Comment: @UV0.You have no basis to determine where in the 30 minute cycle they are, nor any basis for their "free time".  And yes, the probability of the message will have been checked by t:30s = 1.

Comment: And can anyone build some basis to determine it or not.

Comment: @UV0 you have given no basis to determine the probability of "they are busy" for any point in time.   Without that, you have nothing to use for a time domain variance.

Comment: Also one more thing what i meant in second comment is considering person schedule same for all 30 min and interval between them and in between interval he is completely free so there is equal chance at any instant to see in between intervals then can we determine function

Comment: @UV0 You keep changing the scenario words without adding any constraints, so still the answer is "no".  You have no given no probability nor basis to calculate one that they will check when they are free ("there is a chance" is not a probability).   You have no basis to determine when during your defined 30 minute cycle you send the message to them, so it is equally probable that you message is anywhere in that cycle.

Comment: Ok thanks got it

Comment: They r free all the time

Comment: @UV0 "They r free all the time" is a change from your original scenario.  BTW it is considered polite to mark when you edit your initial question e.g. changing the structure removing  "if they have time".    Still you have no basis to determine where in the 30m cycle you are nor anything to calculate about "there is also chance".   All you know with your scenario constraints is the probability that the message will have been read after 30 minutes, which is 1.

Comment: Ok, thanks for ur time,

Comment: @UV0 In re-reading all your writings, I now am wondering if this confusion is a language problem...   Is your actual question this:   "A person checks their messages at least every 30 minutes.   When you send a message, what is the probability that it has been read after 10 minutes? What about after 20 minutes?".

Comment: Ya sort a like that so at last i added a- at particular instant or for seconds

Comment: The main issue is we dont know at which point we send a message and second is we dont know by possibility somehow when will an electron flow in his head and he just check it.

Comment: @UV0 Now this is a pick beads from a known collection problem.    If in minutes, the probability that they read the message in any particular minute is 1/30.   The probability that the message was read after X minutes is X / 30, up to 30 minutes when the probability is 1.   30 minutes is 1800 seconds, so if you want seconds the math is the same.

Comment: Ya but in beads we know where we have started we know how many beads were there initially

Comment: It matches with poisson distro little how, but next event is dependent on last so i dont know if we can use it

Comment: @UV0 Since you don't know where in the cycle they are, that is not a factor in the probability calculation.   You can't use what you don't know, as all possibilities are equally likely and therefore have no effect on the calculations.

Comment: If i dont know where in cycle they are, can i just assign 1/30 probability for 1st minute just like that?

Comment: Ok, possibilties r equally likely.

Comment: @UV0 Yes, given what you know (and the constraints you defined) that is your only calculation, after 1 minute 1/30 probability, after 5 minutes 5/30, etc.

Comment: Ok one last thing if you dont have issue.

Comment: What if person checks after each 30 min is already average of past experience of what he do then will this same.

Comment: Or shall i ask que again with this on home.

Comment: @UV0.  Again changing the scenario, without adding any useable concrete details.  "average of past experience" isn't a quantity that can be used, and you already stated that the 30 minute cycle is not dependent upon when they last checked messages, otherwise this would be beads with replacement problem.   Since reading after 30 minutes and reading anytime are not distinguishable, how you did quantify the distribution of values that created this "average"?  And what is your particular goal with this series of questions on changing scenarios?

Comment: @UV0 as David Diaz already pointed out, once you quantify the "average" this target becomes a poisson distribution.

Comment: Something which could keep track of someones messaging habit based with one have his complete record based on social medias we with all records

Comment: @UV0  With your clarification that you are discussing real-world scenarios, I will state you seem to have gone down a blind alley in thinking about probabilities at all.  Obviously a person does not check messages every 30 minutes 24 hours a day, even if they do check messages 48 times a day during the 16 hours they are awake (which does average to once every 30 minutes in 24 hours), and even for the most frequent users the last time they checked for messages "restarts the clock" for the next check. You are ignoring too many variables.

Comment: Oh, ya you are right

Comment: That will go normally But thinking of busy user with schedule like this of 30 min so no check in interval distribusion will increase linearly, right?

Comment: Variables can be reduces considering large group like poisson.

Comment: @UV0 we are now getting off topic from your initial question & my answer.   I know you are new here, so FYI StackExchange comments sections are for clairification on the initial question asked or the answer, not for extended discussions.   You can consider writing a better worded complete problem, including your actual desired goal objective (making predictions of (?) about someone's future behavior) if you want, though you would benefit from stating what you have tried or considered, given the information you have gathered here.